# ungrading glashfish from command line

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I tried to start my glashfish in eclipse but I got the error: S`erver GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6) at localhost failed to start.`

and suggested this:

```
The configuration data for this domain must be upgraded to run with this
version of the software. To upgrade the data, run:
    asadmin start-domain --upgrade
Then start the domain normally.
Command start-domain failed.
```

my question is how do i upgrade this from the command line?

in my glasfish folder, I have the bin folder and inside the bin is contained a file called asadmin.. when I cd to bin, and run the asadmin start-domain --upgrade, it complains that the asadmin command is not a command..
Anyone knows how to run glassfish from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the way you described. If you are on Linux you could try

```
./asadmin start-domain --upgrade
```

if the current directory is not in your search path.

Comment: I am using mac and like you said, it should have worked but not. just confused ..

Comment: Did you try it with "./" before the command? The asadmin should be an executable file. Can you verify it?

Comment: Thanks alot. The problem was the port was not free, had to kill it and then tried again with the ./asadmin start-domain option and everything worked fine. thanks.